# Prevent setting of properties in designer when control is dropped

Tags: wpf, designer

I have created a custom control in WPF inheriting from a button. Unfortunately I also seem to have inherited the setting of button size etc. when dropping it onto my window in designer mode. For example I get this:

```
<myControls:CustomButton Content="Button" 
                         Height="23" Name="customButton1" Width="75" />
```

How can I prevent the Content, Height and Width properties from being explicitly set by the designer when dropping the button onto the window? The default values I want to use are already set in the style. This is what I want:

```
<myControls:CustomButton Name="customButton1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can prevent this behaviour.

In my case (VS2012) the height is set to auto (no explicit height) so the height auto-sizes depending on the current font. The width is set to 75.

The same values are used using Blend so I can only assume these value are read from metadata.

However you can remove most of these attributes by right-clicking the button in the designer and selecting:

> Reset Layout | All

which leaves you with

```
<Button Content="Button"/>
```

Comment: Ok, but where are the values coming from? 23 and 75 in particular. I would get by with these properties being set if I could at least change the default values.